# Changing html input image with javascript eventhandler

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of building a very simple blogging tool for my personal website. One feature I'm working on is a comments section. Next to each blog post on my website is a button that, once clicked, shows the comments for that particular blog post.

The comment buttons are created dynamically in javascript with

```
  var commentLinks = document.createElement("INPUT");
        commentLinks.setAttribute("type", "image");
        commentLinks.setAttribute("src", "linkredacted");
        commentLinks.setAttribute("id", "commentButton"+i);
        commentLinks.addEventListener("onmouseover", function(){
    changeSrc(commentLinks);
}, false);
```

The problem I am facing is that the mouseover event never fires. I have verified that my URL paths are correct and that the original button is created successfully, but no matter what I try I cannot get the button to resize after the mouseover event. Here is the **changeSrc** function that the code above calls:

```
function changeSrc(commentLinks)
{
  commentLinks.src = "linkredacted";
}
```

I have also tried using **setAttribute** which did not work, as well as placing the entirety of the function call in one anonymous function, which also did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just use a background-image and CSS. It's 2020, not 2000. :P

Comment: The purpose of building project from scratch is to push myself to learn Javascript fully so using CSS is not the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mouseover. Not onmouseover  `commentLinks.addEventListener("onmouseover", function(){` should be `commentLinks.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){`

Comment: See response. Thank you for the answer.